# Unable to Parse the JSON format data in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

The data that is being acquired by this code, is not being formatted into proper csv format.

```
import requests
import csv

def Download_data():
    s = requests.Session()
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    s.headers.update(headers)
    resp = s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?csv=true&index=NIFTY%2050')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    data_79 = resp.text
    data_79 = resp.text.replace('","', '')
    with open('___N50__.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows([line.split(',') for line in data_79.splitlines()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Download_Fresh_data2()
```

The headers are all in rows rather than one column.

I have tried to arrive at this code after lot of learning, but it is still insufficient knowledge from my end.  Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to skip the header rows and explicitly add them:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests


def download_data():
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?csv=true&index=NIFTY%2050"
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36"}

    with requests.Session() as request:
        request.get(url="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market", headers=headers)
        response = request.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.raise_for_status())

    df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=StringIO(initial_value=response.text), skiprows=13, header=None,
                     names=["SYMBOL", "OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "PREV. CLOSE", "LTP",
                            "CHNG", "%CHNG", "VOLUME", "52W H", "52W L",
                            "30 D %CHNG", "365 D % CHNG", "TODAY"])
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf="/path/to/file/N50.csv", index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the data with a text editor? `resp.text` seems to start with a BOM, and each field of the header ends with a linefeed. IMHO the data needs some cleaning:

```py
    # ...

    // strip BOM:
    data_79 = re.sub(r'\A[^"]+"', '"', resp.text, 1)

    // strip unwanted linefeeds:
    data_79 = re.sub(r'([^"])\n', '\\1', data_79)

    // save the data in a file
    with open('___N50__.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        file.write(data_79)
```

Comment: Dear Fravadona, thanks for pointing that out, it is surely the sole reason for the mix up happening when exporting to csv. But the cleaning is slightly advanced for my level at the moment, because when I remove some characters, it is concatenating multiple numerals or strings or numbers.. for example, when I removed something like '","' which was repeating too many times, it took me time to know what it was a crime in my situation. My brain was already fried and exhausted with over a week of trials.. it was trial attempt 79, as you can see above.. But I appreciate you pointing it out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the url you are accessing has a valid CSV file, then you can direcly read the csv into pandas dataframe and then save to local machine as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
c.to_csv(r"C:\users\123\Downloads\countries.csv")
```

Comment: Dear MSS, it didn;t work in my case, as it was json output from the website, converted to csv.. I was trying to do it programmatically, which means I was accessing the raw data, and hence needed to convert it to csv myself, rather than the website doing it for me, while saving upon clicking the link to download.. If you know of a way to do it efficiently, please post it here, as it will be mighty help.. Thank you!!

Comment: I can only show you the path!!! Just compare my answer with accepted answer.